# local variable referenced before assignment discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

i was creating my own discord bot and for some reason i allways sent me output when i ran my command

local variable referenced 'thing' before assignment

and in these lines of code it told me that 'thing' is not defined

```
options = starter_thing
    if thing in db.keys():
      options = options + db["thing"]
```

and

```
def update_thing(thing_message):
    if thing in db.keys():
        thing = db["thing"]
        thing.append(thing_message)
        db["thing"] = thing
    else:
        db["thing"] = [thing_message
```

Answer (score 3):

the key is a string:

```
if "thing" in db.keys():
    ...
```

or *assign* a value to the variable thing first:

```
thing = "thing"
if thing in db.keys():
    ...
```

Comment: thanks this really helped. iam new to this stuff so thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell in thhose code snippets, the 'thing' variable does not exist anywhere, so Python doesn't know what you mean when you use 'thing'

Try assigning something to 'thing' like
`thing = "thingToCheck"`